# how to add tuple values to each key of a dictionary whose values are nd.array as well?

Tags: python, append, ordereddict

Let's say I have a dictionary like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict()

d["1"] = [10,10]
d["2"] = [20,20]
d["3"] = [30,30]
```

And I want it to become

```
OrderedDict([('1', [[10, 10], [12, 12]]), ('2', [20, 20]), ('3', [30, 30])])
```

I tried `d.setdefault("1", []).append([12,12])`, but it's made

```
OrderedDict([('1', [10, 10, [12, 12]]), ('2', [20, 20]), ('3', [30, 30])])
```

When I type `print(d["1"][1])`, it should print out `[12, 12]`

How should change the code? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: did you try d.prepend()

Comment: are you sure you want it to become this? This is not a good format. I would propose changing all the values to *nested lists*. Otherwise, you can just type it: `d["1"] = [d["1"], [12, 12]]`

Comment: @Jeril, it didn't work.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis, I think I need that exact format, because I will have to append `[x,y]` type array every 4 seconds automatically inside the loop and access them by their index just as shown above (`print(d["1"][1])`)

Answer (score 0):

Just change `d["1"]` assignment to: `d["1"] = [[10,10]]`, and your line `d.setdefault("1", []).append([12,12])` will do the right job

Comment: well thanks, but I cant change its format, I should accept it in that format, example here is for representation sake